# Cosmos DB pre trigger how to fetch value from another row

Tags: c#, triggers, azure-cosmosdb

In Cosmos DB I have trigger, this is pretrigger. Method for this trigger looks like this:

```
 function CalculateFields(){
        var context = getContext(); 
        var request = context.getRequest(); 
        // this is the current request 
        var itemToCreate = request.getBody(); 

        if(itemToCreate["fileType"] == "DivisionConfig")
        {
           itemToCreate["column1"] = 2 * item1["column3"];
        }
```

and I want to fetch value from another row, selected by id. `itemToCreate` is current item, how to get item for id = 1?
Can I do that in this method, or rather I have to pass variable in C# code when I call this trigger:

```
using (CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(Endpoint, Key))
            {
                var container = client.GetContainer(DatabaseId, CollectionId);

                ItemResponse<T> response2 = await container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey("Mypk"), new ItemRequestOptions { PreTriggers = new List<string> { "CalculateFields" } });
                return response2;
            }
```

---

`item1["column3"]` is another row from the same collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-triggers can only operate on the item itself and cannot accept parameters. I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do here but maybe look at using a Post-Trigger instead.

Comment: I want to calculate column value base on value from another row. I've added same code in my post. So maybe there is a way to pass value again item["column3"] ?

Comment: The only possible way I can see this working is to use a stored procedure. But the row needs to be in the same logical partition to work. If not then you will need to make two calls from the Cosmos client. Thanks.